# how to block the unauthorized user using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

***I'm new to SpringSecurity.***

This my Spring-security-Context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" path-type="ant">
        <form-login login-page="/jack/login" authentication-failure-url="/jack/login" default-target-url="/jack/home"  />

        <intercept-url pattern="/themes/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/**/*.png" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/**/*.jpg" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/upload-users" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/logincheck" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/sessionExpire" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jack/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/jack/logout"
            logout-success-url="/jack/login" invalidate-session="true" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/jack/logout" >
                <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"  expired-url="/jack/logout"/>               
        </session-management>
        <security:custom-filter ref="expiredSessionFilter" after="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
    </http>




    <beans:bean id="expiredSessionFilter" class="com.jack.web.filter.ExpiredSessionFilter">
    </beans:bean>




    <!-- Authentication providers -->
     <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.jack.security.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider" > 
        <!-- <security:custom-authentication-provider />  -->
        <!-- <beans:property name="userDetailsService"  ref="userDetailsService"/>  -->
    </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

case 1:
in `web.xml`
**jack** is the springcontext name

in `security-context.xml`
**jack** is the pattern like */jack/login*

when i give URL like

```
localhost:8080/project/jack/login
```

this spring security works very well

case 2:
in `web.xml`
**xxx** is the springcontext name

in security-context.xml
**jack** is the pattern like */jack/login*

***i'm not change anything in securitycontext.xml***

When I give

```
localhost:8080/project/xxx/login
```

spring security allows the user to enter into my application.

after logout, if user copy - paste's the home page url means spring security
    not redirecting the user into login page.

How can i redirect the user to
    spring login page or is there any other option i have?

Comment: the problem is spring security allow the user without asking the credential

Answer (score 1):

Try using project in intercept-url pattern and instead of jack use ** there and then rest of the url you want to restrict.

Eg. Instead `/jack/upload-users` use `/project/**/upload-users`.

And also note that **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** is used to allow access to user even if he's not authenticated in application.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are per default allowing access to all URL by using

```
  `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />`
```

So you need to Blacklist every URL you want to protect. Spring security is checking the patterns in the order listed in the configuration. The first matching pattern is applied without any further checking. So if no pattern matches the `pattern="/**"` will be applied granting anyone access.

Better practice would be to deny access by default this means setting the access for `pattern="/**"` to the most permissiv role you have or at least to require authentication (for example using `access="isAuthenticated()"`) This way you are using a whitelist approach and don't have to worry to much about missing url-patterns.

**Update**

To comment on the logout problem. You redirect to a custom `logout-url`. What is beyond that url? The spring security logout routine is called via `/j_spring_security_logout` which is the default if you don't call a `logout-url` otherwise you should call `/j_spring_security_logout` in your custom logout routine.